# Serialize and deserialize objects in C ++

Tags: mysql, c++11, serialization, deserialization

I'm new to C ++, I can not find a detailed example of how to serialize an object in binary so I can save it to the mysql server and then be deserialized.

The object looks like this:

```
class house{
        public:
          int houseNumber;
          bool isEmpty;
          Dweller *dweller;
};
     class Dweller{
       public:
         int phoneNumber;
         bool man;
         Backpack backpack;
};
     class Backpack{
      public:
        int item1;
        int item2;
        int item3;
        int item4;
        float weight;
        bool empty;
};
```

I have to serialize the house object, which owns the other objects.

Comment: Any kind of binary format? Is a protobuf an option? https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/overview

Comment: I think protobuf would be an option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem using:

```
#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
```

See I used  `#include "boost/serialization/vector.hpp"`  because now the 'dweller' are in a vector to make things easier

Then the code stayed like this:

```
class house{
    public:
      int houseNumber;
      bool isEmpty;
      std::vector<Dweller> dweller;
    private:
      friend class boost::serialization::access;
      template <class archive>
      void serialize(archive &ar, const unsigned int version)
      {
        ar &houseNumber;
        ar &isEmpty;
        ar &dweller;
      }
};
class Dweller{
    public:
      int phoneNumber;
      bool man;
      Backpack backpack;
    private:
      friend class boost::serialization::access;
      template <class archive>
      void serialize(archive &ar, const unsigned int version)
      {
        ar &phoneNumber;
        ar &man;
        ar &backpack;
      }
};
class Backpack{
    public:
      int item1;
      int item2;
      int item3;
      int item4;
      float weight;
      bool empty;
    private:
      friend class boost::serialization::access;
      template <class archive>
      void serialize(archive &ar, const unsigned int version)
      {
        ar &item1;
        ar &item2;
        ar &item3;
        ar &item4;
        ar &weight;
        ar &empty;
      }
};
```

So to serialize I used:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
  Backpack _backpack;
  _backpack.item1 = 0;
  _backpack.item1 = 1;
  _backpack.item1 = 2;
  _backpack.item1 = 3;
  _backpack.item1 = 4;
  _backpack.weight = 3.21;
  _backpack.empty = false;
  Dweller _dweller1;
  _dweller.phoneNumber = 1234567;
  _dweller.man = false;
  _dweller.backpack = _backpack;
  Dweller _dweller2;
  _dweller.phoneNumber = 7654321;
  _dweller.man = true;
  _dweller.backpack = _backpack;

  std::vector<Dweller> _dwellers;
  _dwellers.push_back(_dweller1);
  _dwellers.push_back(_dweller2);
  house _house;
  _house.houseNumber = 4;
  _house.isEmpty = false;
  _house.dweller = _dwellers;

  /*Serializing*/
  std::stringstream ss;
  boost::archive::binary_oarchive oa(ss);
  oa << _house;
  /*Deserializing*/
  boost::archive::binary_iarchive ia(ss);
  house _house2;
  ia >> _house2;
}
```